# Ruby on Rails based website and app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I have started coding during my free time for over a year now. I had a social community idea which will be location based which basically deals with locations and nearby trending places. 
I did some 10 minute video about scaffolding and have been totally smitten by Ruby on Rails. I really want to go ahead and make it on RoR.

However I don't know how to work with databases dealing with locations. I have done some research and looks like Mongo.DB is the one which is the most popular considering what 4square did. But I was wondering can we work with Active Record ? I saw a gem called geocoder , will it help me with the problem I am trying to tackle ?

Again , I have only coded in C++ , and haven't exactly worked with databases .

Which gems and tools should I be using for it ? Ruby and Mongo.db or Ruby on Rails simple using gems like geocoder ?

I felt encouraged seeing a website called www.foodspotting.com  , it shows they have coded in ruby on rails ! Can someone give some good combination so that I can start thinking in the right direction ?

ruby on rails with mongo?
ruby with sinatra ?

although I am trying to stick to the RoR genre , as I have subscribed to the Michael Hartl tutorials .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using **PostgreSQL** with **PostGIS**. You'll need the `activerecord-postgis-adapter` gem to make that work with ActiveRecord.

However, a word of warning, dealing with spatial data isn't easy, and if this is your first Ruby on Rails application *and* your first database-backed application I would say that you're biting off a fair bit more than you can be expected to chew. Start small, start easy, work your way up.

Answer (score 0):

First try to make some small applications in ruby on rails using database like MongoDB. I suggested this because you are going to use location based application implementation.

A very nice tutorial step by step that will let you go for it is -

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started

Regarding Geocoder - It provides object geocoding (by street or IP address), reverse geocoding (coordinates to street address), distance queries for ActiveRecord and Mongoid, result caching, and more. Designed for Rails but works with Sinatra and other Rack frameworks too. 
You will find the documentation of geocoder to let you start over here -

http://rubydoc.info/gems/geocoder/1.1.5/frames

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of choosing between MongoDB and PostgreSQL or between RoR and Sinatra.

What you really need is a RoR plugin/engine/module/whatever that can help you with map viewing, navigation, locating and geocoding. The geocoder gem is a component of this software stack.

The geocoding/mapping/navigation toolset you will choose will impose you the DB (most likely PostgreSQL with GIS extensions, that is: PostGIS) and many others implementation details.

A very well-known and largely appreciated mapping/navigation software stack is the one developed and used by OpenStreetMap (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) that (you are a lucky guy...) is even based on RoR.

Have a look at their solutions and have a talk with the developers on their forum/mailing-list. I'm sure you will find what you need.